# Powershell - Create table from existing arrays

Tags: powershell

Language: PowerShell

Hi all

I have two lists of arrays and I'm trying to join these lists together and create a table from them. I've tried a few methods but I haven't had much luck. Any suggestions?

Building the table:

```
$fullName = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
    firstName = $FName
    lastName = $LName
}
```

Output:

```
lastName         firstName
------           -------
{Doe,Dome,Donny} {John, Jane, Mary}
```

Whereas I'm attempting to get an output of:

```
firstName         lastName
------            -------
John              Doe
Jane              Dome
Mary              Donny
```

Comment: Using the function from the linked answer: `$fname, $lname | Join-Array firstName, lastName`